# Signature Mismatch ocaml

Tags: ocaml, functor

First the code:

```
module type ENV_CORE =
sig 
type variable 
type 'a environment
exception Unbound_variable
val empty : unit -> variable
val bind : 'a -> 'a environment -> 'a environment
val unbind : variable -> 'a -> 'a environment -> 'a environment
val is_bound : variable -> 'a environment -> bool
val lookup : variable -> 'a environment -> bool
val fold : (variable -> 'a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a environment -> 'b -> 'b
end;;


module EnvCoreList : ENV_CORE =

struct
    type variable = string list
    type 'a environment = variable * variable -> 'a
    exception Unbound_variable
    let empty () = []
    let bind elt l = elt::l
    let rec unbind elt l =
        match l with
        |[] -> raise Unbound_variable
        |a::r -> if (elt = a)
            then r
            else a::(unbind elt r)
    let rec is_bound elt l =
        match l with
        |[] -> raise Unbound_variable
        |a::r -> if (elt = a)
            then true
            else is_bound elt r
    let rec lookup elt l =
        match l with
        |[] -> false
        |a::r -> if (elt = a)
            then true
            else lookup elt r
    let rec fold f rho gamma =
        match rho with
        |[] -> gamma
        |a::r -> f a (fold f r gamma)
end;;
```

When I compile it I get the following error:

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
   Modules do not match:
     sig
       type variable = string list
       type 'a environment = variable * variable -> 'a
       exception Unbound_variable
       val empty : unit -> 'a list
       val bind : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list
       val unbind : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list
       val is_bound : 'a -> 'a list -> bool
       val lookup : 'a -> 'a list -> bool
       val fold : ('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b -> 'b
     end
   is not included in
     ENV_CORE
   Values do not match:
     val bind : 'a -> 'a list -> 'a list
   is not included in
     val bind : 'a -> 'a environment -> 'a environment
```

What I don't understand is how the more specific type isn't included in the more general type?
I couldnt find any similar questions and havent been able to resolve this issue. 
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious relation between the types `'a list` and `'a environment`. I don't see why you would consider either to be more general than the other.

It seems to me you should either change your definition of `environment` in your implementation, or you should rewrite `bind` so that it works on the type you specify for `environment`.

Comment: I have to write the signature for the heart `ENV_CORE` environments and the module (`EnvCoreList: ENV_CORE`) that implements environments with list of associations